Measurability of the preimage of a sequence of functions
I am trying to solve the excercise (see  the picture) and I don't know how to answer c). My idea for a counter example is to build a sequence of funtions such that the points for which it doesn't converge equal a vitalli set. Does this work? Or am I on the wrong path?
Cheers
Image:


Since convergent real sequences are exactly Cauchy sequences, you can write $\{x\in \mathbb R, \lim_{k\to \infty}f_k(x)$ exists in $\mathbb R\}$ as $\bigcap_{k\in \mathbb N}\bigcup_{N\in \mathbb N}\bigcap_{n,m > N}\{x\in \mathbb R, |f_n(x)-f_m(x)| < \frac 1k\}$.
